# VBA Array Not Updating Existing Values *Updated*

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

**EDITED TO INCLUDE FULL CODE, followed by sample snippet of data, and output***

In my code below, for some reason I cannot get my array to update its values. For some reason the values stay as they were originally defined, you can see the third one in lineTotals stays at 2435 in the output despite trying to add values to it:

```vb
    Sub SummarizeData()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
        ' Find the last row with data
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
        ' Create a dictionary to store totals for each LineId
        Dim lineTotals As Object
        Set lineTotals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
        ' Loop through each row of data
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the data starts from row 2
        ' Get data from the current row
        LineId = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        poundsProduced = ws.Cells(i, "P").Value
        poundsWaste = ws.Cells(i, "O").Value
        wasteType = ws.Cells(i, "L").Value
        shiftId = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        styleIndicator = ws.Cells(i, "X").Value
    
        ' Check if LineId is not "-" or "All" and styleIndicator is "dataRow"
        If LineId <> "-" And LineId <> "All" And styleIndicator = "dataRow" Then
            ' Check if LineId exists in the dictionary
            If Not lineTotals.Exists(LineId) Then
                ' If it doesn't, add it with initial values
                lineTotals.Add LineId, Array(0#, 0#, 2435#, 0#, 0#, 0#, 0#, 0#)
            End If
    
            Dim pounds As Double
            pounds = lineTotals(LineId)(0)
            Dim wastetot As Double
            wastetot = lineTotals(LineId)(1)
            Dim pkgwaste As Double
            pkgwaste = lineTotals(LineId)(2)
            
            ' Update totals for the current LineId in the dictionary
            lineTotals(LineId)(0) = lineTotals(LineId)(0) + poundsProduced
            lineTotals(LineId)(1) = lineTotals(LineId)(1) + poundsWaste
    
            ' Check wasteType and update specific totals
            If wasteType = "PACKAGING" Then
    
    
                pkgwaste = pkgwaste + poundsWaste
                
    
                lineTotals(LineId)(2) = pkgwaste
                Debug.Print lineTotals(LineId)(2)
    
            ElseIf wasteType = "PROCESSING" Then
                lineTotals(LineId)(3) = lineTotals(LineId)(3) + poundsWaste
            End If
    
            ' Update top five shifts with the highest percentage of PoundsWaste compared to PoundsProduced
            If poundsProduced > 0 And poundsWaste > 0 Then
                wastePercentage = poundsWaste / poundsProduced * 100
                If wastePercentage > lineTotals(LineId)(4) Then
                    ' Update shift details if the current percentage is higher
                    lineTotals(LineId)(4) = wastePercentage
                    lineTotals(LineId)(5) = shiftId
                End If
            End If
            'Debug.Print "LineId: " & LineId & ", PoundsProduced: " & poundsProduced & ", PoundsWaste: " & poundsWaste & ", WasteType: " & wasteType & ", ShiftId: " & shiftId & ", StyleIndicator: " & styleIndicator
            'Debug.Print "Line Totals: " & Join(lineTotals(LineId), ", ")
        End If
    Next i
    
        ' Display the summary on a new sheet called "Summary"
        Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
        Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    
        ' Headers
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "LineId"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total PoundsProduced"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = "Total PoundsWaste"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 4).Value = "Total PACKAGING Type Waste"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 5).Value = "Total PROCESSING Type Waste"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 6).Value = "Top Shift for Highest Percentage Waste"
        summarySheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = "Highest Percentage Waste"
    
        ' Populate the summary
        Dim summaryRow As Long
        summaryRow = 4
    
        For Each LineId In lineTotals.Keys
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 1).Value = LineId
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 2).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(0)
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 3).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(1)
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 4).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(2)
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 5).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(3)
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 6).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(5)
            summarySheet.Cells(summaryRow, 7).Value = lineTotals(LineId)(4)
            summaryRow = summaryRow + 1
        Next LineId
    End Sub
```

Sample data:
[image: Sample data]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: "Displays" where?  What you have above doesn't display anything.  It just updates a dictionary in memory.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can't update a item in `Dict` object as `lineTotals(LineId)(0) = lineTotals(LineId)(0) + poundsProduced`.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, declare all variables, and post the complete code from `Sub...` to `End Sub` so we can test it. Also, add some sample data, a screenshot, and a description of what the code is supposed to do. Then we will be able to suggest how to tackle this. BTW you cannot change the values of the elements in an array held by an item of a dictionary.

Comment: ADODB SQL is an option. You can get the expected result with less code. btw, [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

### A 'Cannot Update Array in Dictionary' Workaround

- One way would be to copy the array to another array (variable). Then update this copy and copy it back to the dictionary. That seems quite ugly and inefficient. I opted for another approach.
- Here is kind of a blueprint for a 'common' approach with quite some guesswork. For your next question, keep in mind that the more information you share the better the answer.

```vb
Sub WorkAround()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Other preceding code...

    Dim lineTotals As Object
    Set lineTotals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lineTotals.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case
    
    Dim i As Long, LineId As String, styleIndicator As String
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Get data from the current row
        LineId = CStr(ws.Cells(i, "F").Value)
        styleIndicator = CStr(ws.Cells(i, "X").Value)
        ' Check if LineId is not "-" or "All" and styleIndicator is "dataRow"
        If LineId <> "-" And LineId <> "All" And styleIndicator = "dataRow" Then
            If Not lineTotals.Exists(LineId) Then
                Set lineTotals = New Collection
            End If
            lineTotals.Add LineId, i
        End If
    Next i
    ' Now you have a dictionary whose keys hold the Line Ids,
    ' while each corresponding item holds a collection of the rows
    ' where the key (Line Id) was found.
    
    Dim Arr() As Variant, Key As Variant, Item As Variant
    
    Dim poundsProduced As Variant
    Dim poundsWaste As Variant
    Dim wasteType As String
    Dim shiftId ' ?
    
    For Each Key In lineTotals.Keys ' dictionary keys: Line Ids
        ReDim Arr(0 To 7) ' array: various totals; adjust size!
        For Each Item In lineTotals(Key) ' collection items: Line Id Rows
            
            poundsProduced = ws.Cells(Item, "P").Value
            If VarType(poundsProduced) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                Arr(0) = Arr(0) + poundsProduced
            End If
            
            poundsWaste = ws.Cells(Item, "O").Value
            If VarType(poundsWaste) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                Arr(1) = Arr(1) + poundsWaste
                wasteType = CStr(ws.Cells(Item, "L").Value)
                If StrComp(wasteType, "PACKAGING", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Arr(2) = Arr(2) + poundsWaste
                End If
            End If
            
            shiftId = ws.Cells(Item, "C").Value
            
            ' Other totals...
            
        Next Item
        ' Replace the collection of rows with the array of totals.
        lineTotals(Key) = Arr
    Next Key
    ' Now you have a dictionary whose keys hold the Line Ids,
    ' while each corresponding item holds an array of the totals.

    ' What you wanna do with it?
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I understand what you're doing here. Thanks for the feedback as well for future questions. I edited my original question to provide more helpful context!